# How can I adapt old thick wiring entering my 30 yr old furnace to fit into the clip on slot on modern day circuit breaker switch?

Tags: wiring

My 30 year old furnace blew one of its breaker switches and shortly after blew the second breaker switch. I had a service technician look at the furnace and he confirmed this. He said he did not think he could find replacement switches and that I may need to replace the whole furnace. I found this a little strange and thought it was a cash grab so I opened the furnace back up and looked at the switches.

They are part of an assembled unit but I can open up the unit and replace them, piece of cake. Except for one little problem. The old circuit breaker switches are hard wired into the system. They have VERY thick wires (thicker than a pencil) where the power enters them. ALL modern day circuit breakers have a slot where they clip/mount onto a bracket where the power enters. The old breaker switches allowed wires to be screwed into place at both ends instead of just the end power exits them.

Is there an adapter I can attach to the wire that allows me to attach them to the modern day slot in the circuit breaker switch? They are 50A and 60A breaker switches. (double switches) (2 pole?).

EDIT: The two breaker switches I need to replace are both labeled "common trip".

Comment: Why does the furnace have breaker switches at the furnace? Does the circuit which powers it have breakers in the panel?

Comment: Wondering the same thing as @JimStewart - are you trying to replace the breaker switch in the furnace unit with a new one that's normally installed in a circuit breaker panel?

Comment: Going to need some brand names or photos or something for this one. I'm not at all sure what we're talking about. "Breaker switches" and huge wire? o_O

Comment: I have replaced similar breakers with DIN rail breakers they have normal screw terminals at top and bottom but I think they maxed out at 40A, on my phone now but will try to get online tonight.

Comment: Can you post photos of the existing breakers?  I'm pretty certain I know what you're really after here, but want to double check and can't see your wiring from where I'm sitting!  Also, I take it this is an electric furnace, correct?

Comment: 2 pole 50 amp E92 B50, 2 pole 63 amp E92 B63.  If you google ether number it will take you to there page. There are many manufacturers this is just 1 example / brand of a DIN circuit breaker.

Comment: Is this for the resistive heat on a heat pump?  You really need to update the question with the make/model of the system.

Comment: @EdBeal -- many DIN rail breakers are IEC compliant, but *not* UL 489 compliant

Comment: The ones I used actually exceeded the standard requirements and did have ul stamps. That might be why I remember them maxing out at 40 amps. I am sure they had 10000 intrupt rating and were good up to 480 AC, and DC but I don't remember the DC voltages. The ones I gave part numbers to I believe also had similar stats but I was am on my phone when at remote locations so it is hard to search.

Answer (score 3):

### This is what unit mount breakers are for

Most modern circuit breakers are designed to attach to a panelboard's busbars, hence the clip.  However, you don't want that since these breakers are providing subdivided protection per NEC 422.11(F)(1), with fat branch circuit wiring coming in and no busbars in sight within the enclosure:

> **(F) Electric Heating Appliances Employing Resistance-Type Heating Elements Rated More Than 48 Amperes.**
>
> **(1) Electric Heating Appliances.** Electric heating appliances employing resistance-type heating elements rated
>   more than 48 amperes, other than household appliances
>   with surface heating elements covered by 422.11 (B), and
>   commercial-type heating appliances covered by 422.11 (D),
>   shall have the heating elements subdivided. Each subdivided load shall not exceed 48 amperes and shall be protected at not more than 60 amperes.
>
> These supplementary overcurrent protective devices
>   shall be (1) factory-installed within or on the heater enclosure or provided as a separate assembly by the heater
>   manufacturer; (2) accessible; and (3) suitable for branch-
>   circuit protection.
>
> The main conductors supplying these overcurrent protective devices shall be considered branch-circuit conductors.

What you need instead is a *unit mount breaker*, sometimes called a *cable-in/cable-out breaker* -- these circuit breakers are designed to mount directly into a box, usually through a mounting scheme such as the ubiquitous DIN rail or a set of panel mounting clips, instead of to a panelboard busbar, and have wire lug terminals on both sides of the breaker.  An example is depicted below.

[image: representative QOU2xx circuit breaker]

However, you need a breaker listed to UL 489 for this application.  Look for something from the Square D QOU or Eaton QC lines, for instance, although several other UL 489 listed DIN rail breaker lines are available as well -- you'll need to order them in from an electrical supply house though, along with the appropriate mounting hardware if you are changing breaker types (a like-for-like replacement should fit the existing mounts though).